# How to get spatial reference of a shapefile using python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I always use arcpy.GetParameterAsText to get the spatial reference from the user. There should be a way to decide what is the spatial reference of a shapefile but I can't find it. Something like Describe....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SR = arcpy.Describe(inFC).spatialReference
```

where inFC is an input shapefile or feature class. It returns a [SpatialReference object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/spatialreference.htm).

Comment: Jason...The superfluous code was designed to be informative for the OP who doesn't appear to have much experience with the Describe object...I would wish that you returned it

Comment: I think the edit was appropriate. I am not sure what the other code demonstrates, but it does not seem to be relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Thirty years teaching down the drain :)  it is amazing what someone can get out of a code snippet

Answer (score 4):

if you want to spell out the name of the Spatial reference for feature class `fc`, use:

```
# Get spatial reference of the feature class
spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference

# print the spatial reference
print spatialRef.Name
```

Printing only the `spatialRef` (without `.Name` at the end) prints only

```
print spatialRef
<geoprocessing spatial reference object object at 0x06623080>
```

while

```
print spatialRef.Name
```

returns the name of CS:

```
GCS_WGS_1984
```

(based on GIS Programming and Automation class: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/115  )